# Selenium grid is configured on windows server 2016 and we observe the windows server is crashing with A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP error

Tags: windows, selenium, server, crash, selenium-grid

Selenium grid is configured on windows server 2016 and we observer the windows server is crashing due to the error  0x000000c2 (0x0000000000000007, 0x0000000074654e56, 0x0000000004070007, 0xffffd988f7f0b5d0). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: c2a8b94d-67ee-4e3f-aa4a-ebf8855cc4d9.

Our windows server management team suspects the issue is with selenium instance running on the server and we have hub and selenium running on individual windows server. Selenium jar which we are using to configure the hub and node is  selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar .

**Hub is started with below command**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub -hubConfig hub.json -log hublog.log
```

**Hub configuration file**

```
{
  "port": 4444,
  "log": "hublog.txt",
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {},
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "role": "hub",
  "debug": true,
  "browserTimeout": 900,
  "timeout": 600,
  "_comment" : "Configuration for Hub - hub.json",
  "prioritizer": null,
  "nodePolling": 2000,
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter" : 1000,
  "downPollingLimit" : 2,
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 1000,
  "platform": "WINDOWS"
}
```

**Node is started with below command**

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="msedgedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig node1.json -log nodelog.log
```

**Node config file**

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
 "cleanUpCycle":5000,
"timeout":600,
"browserTimeout":900,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"maxSession": 15,
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hubPort": 4444,
"hubHost": "<<seleniumhubip>>",

"log":"nodelog.log",
"id":"<<nodehostname>>",
"downPollingLimit" :2,
"nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 1000,
"nodePolling": 2000,
"role": "node",
"unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 1000
}
```

Comment: `0x000000c2` is not an error code. I would not expect a process to crash in response to a non-error. Anyway, you have a memory dump, so load it up in a debugger. That'll take out the guess-work out of diagnosing the issue.

Comment: can you suggest any debugger tool so i can inform my team to use and look into it for more details

Comment: Any [Windows Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/) will do. If your team is more confident with Visual Studio, then its debugger can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in [**Configuring the nodes by command line**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/legacy/grid_2/#configuring-the-nodes-by-command-line):

> By default, starting the node allows for concurrent use of 11 browsers.

You are seeing the error as you are trying to start ***15*** nodes through your configuration as:

```
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ]
```

---

### Solution

As you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) **v3.x** keeping the total number of nodes at 11(maximum) will solve the issue.

Comment: the selenium node and windows server are up and running but while executing the selenium scripts the windows server is getting crashed. 
The documentation, which was pointed, informs about the default value but has not informed about the limitation

Comment: Why not to test with the suggested value to probe if you still face the same error, then we can focus else where if needed.